# cannot find -lboost_system collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, bioinformatics

I am installing the package velocyto.R into R and I am getting the following error.

```
install_github("velocyto-team/velocyto.R")
```

And I am getting the following error.

```
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'velocyto.R'
* removing 'C:/Users/Joel Parker/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/velocyto.R'
```

Has anyone seen this error and how would I fix it?

Comment: You are missing libraries, `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system`. See [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/index.html).

Comment: Looking this issue: https://github.com/velocyto-team/velocyto.R/issues/86#issuecomment-605716024  Developer doesn't have the time or resources to maintain it working on all platform and suggest you to use docker.